# Debugging in Google Colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, google-colaboratory

I am running the following code snippet in google colab in a single cell:

```
%debug
# Create tensors of shape (10, 3) and (10, 2).
x = torch.randn(10, 3)
y = torch.randn(10, 2)

# Build a fully connected layer.
linear = nn.Linear(3, 2)
print ('w: ', linear.weight)
print ('b: ', linear.bias)
```

I wish to debug a piece of code (step through it line by line) to understand what is going on. I wish to step inside the function nn.Linear.

However, when I step through, it does not enter the function at  all. Is there a way to step through nn.Linear line by line? Also, how exactly do I set a breakpoint in nn.Linear? Besides, I wish to step though the snippet line by line as well. However, as the picture shows, the step command automatically steps through and executes the print statement as well.

[image: Step_though_collab]

Answer (score 29):

Since Python 3.7 you can use a built-in [breakpoint function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/). If this is not available, you can use

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

instead.

If you want to execute the next line you can try `n` (next) instead of `s` (step).

Comment: Here are the [debugger commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) for pdb.

Comment: This just crashes for me.

PYDEV DEBUGGER WARNING:
sys.settrace() should not be used when the debugger is being used.
This may cause the debugger to stop working correctly.
If this is needed, please check: 
http://pydev.blogspot.com/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html
to see how to restore the debug tracing back correctly.
Call Location:
  File "", line 334, in set_trace
    sys.settrace(self.trace_dispatch)

--Return--
None
> <ipython-input-4-1a85e0b649d5>(2)<module>()
      1 import pdb
----> 2 pdb.set_trace()

ipdb> s
    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

Answer (score 9):

Use **pdb** built-in breakpoint function according to below commands :

```
import pdb; 
pdb.set_trace()
```

### Command      Description

1. list    Show the current location in the file
2. h(elp)  Show a list of commands, or find help on a specific command
3. q(uit)  Quit the debugger and the program
4. c(ontinue)  Quit the debugger, continue in the program
5. n(ext)  Go to the next step of the program
6. Repeat the previous command
7. p(rint) Print variables
8. s(tep)  Step into a subroutine
9. r(eturn)    Return out of a subroutine

Comment: This crashes:

----> 2 pdb.set_trace()
      3 x = 1
      4 y = 2
      5 z = x * y

ipdb> s
    [... skipped 1 hidden frame]

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py(3436)run_code()
   3434             finally:
   3435                 # Reset our crash handler in place
-> 3436                 sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
   3437         except SystemExit as e:
   3438             if result is not None

Answer (score -1):

For latest use,

```
import pdb; 
pdb.set_trace()
```

You can use inbuilt Breakpoint functions to set breakpoint in nn.Linear.

```
import sys; sys.breakpoint()
```

There are many more available commands for interactive debugging,

```
Command  Description
list     Show the current location in the file
h(elp)   Show a list of commands, or find help on a specific command
q(uit)   Quit the debugger and the program
c(ontinue)  Quit the debugger, continue in the program
n(ext)   Go to the next step of the program
<enter>  Repeat the previous command
p(rint)  Print variables
s(tep)   Step into a subroutine
r(eturn)    Return out of a subroutine
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'breakpoint'

Comment: it doesn't work anymore